# How to Charge Multiple Items at once in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to find a way to get Stripe to charge multiple items in one charge. I'm thinking it would look something like this:

```
$totalitems = [];
if ( $item1 == "true" ) {
    $currentitem = array(
    "amount" => 19999,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "Item 1",
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    );
    array_push($totalitems, $currentitem);
}

if ( $item2 == "true" ) {
    $currentitem = array(
    "amount" => 29999,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "description" => "Item 2",
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    );
    array_push($totalitems, $currentitem);
}

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([$totalitems]);
```

this only charges the first item in the array. Is there a way to charge multiple items at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't charge multiple items in that way. Instead you have a few options:

- simply add up the items on your side and create one charge for the total amount.
- make separate charges for each item.
- use the [Orders API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#orders).

I would suggest going with the first approach, and you can use the charge [metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-metadata) to record which items are included in the charge for your own reference.

Comment: Would you mind motivating why you suggest the first approach?

Comment: Well, in comparison to the alternatives, making multiple charges in quick succession might cause some of the transactions to be flagged by some banks; and using Stripe's Orders API can be a little limiting or cumbersome, as you have to define all your products and prices in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In current Stripe checkout.session.create you can add multiple items within line_item attribute:

```
line_items: [
  // ONE ITEM

  // {
  //   name: product.name,
  //   description: product.description,
  //   images: [product.image],
  //   amount: product.amount,
  //   currency: product.currency,
  //   quantity: validatedQuantity,
  // },

  // MULTIPLE ITEMS
  {
    name: 'F02',
    images: [
      '',
    ],
    amount: '74900',
    currency: 'sek',
    quantity: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'F01',
    images: [
      '',
    ],
    amount: '74900',
    currency: 'sek',
    quantity: 1,
  },
],
```

Comment: Why does this have a bit fat zero next to it? Take your upvote good sir. This was the solution for me. Could've saved 1.5 days of headache had I seen this first. 

Comment: Thank you @RalphTheWonderLlama. Yes that headache I can remember. Well organised docs but then just these small basic things people do over and over and should be super clear when showing via example. Good luck on building the shops.

Comment: Great answer, but anyone know how we would make this line_items object dynamic in PHP? I've tried creating an array and imploding inside the line_items, but no success